# Change SQL query with a parametric query in Oracle

Tags: oracle, hibernate, sql-execution-plan, query-parser

We have an application that uses a framework that we don't have access to it's java classes. I can just see the .class file in byte-code format. So I can't override that class. At that class we have a native query like below:

> "Select col1 from table1 where col2='x'";

I mean where condition is not parametric. As well I don't have access to change the query in the code. the App uses Oracle database and Hibernate as ORM. 
The question is

> "Is there any way to tell Oracle or Hibernate to change this hardcoded query with a parametric one?"

Comment: read this - http://oracleinaction.com/cursor-sharing/

Comment: @OldProgrammer Tanks a lot! good point. we will try it at our DB. if you find my question useful, Please rate me up. :)

Comment: @OldProgrammer, if I'm reading the question correctly, I don't think cursor sharing is relevant